# What does an angel look like?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars Episode: The Phantom Menace*, the first time Anakin saw Padme, they had this conversation:

> ANAKIN: Are you an angel?
>
> PADME: What?
>
> ANAKIN: An angel. I've heard the deep space pilots talk about them. They live on the Moons of Iego I think. They are the most beautiful creatures in the universe. They are good and kind, and so pretty they make even the most hardened spice pirate cry.

<strike>While this is a good flirt line,</strike> I wonder if anyone has made an artistic representation of Iego's angels?

Comment: Anytime someone discussed flirting between Anakin and Padme, I'm tempted to add an "eeeeek" tag

Comment: @DVK: I think the "eeeek" tag is more appropriate for flirting between Luke and Leia. Or maybe that's the "eeeew" tag.

Comment: @gnovice - I think I have enough rep to make them alias tags :)

Comment: @DVK at the time Padme was simply humoring a little boy.  There was nothing sexual about the boyhood crush and nothing inappropriate about the way Padme handled it.

Comment: Iego Angel: http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/lego/images/5/5d/10080_Angel.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100109122415

Comment: Why are you making me think about this scene? Don't you know how hard i've been trying to block it out? ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is actually an entry on Wookieepedia about [Angels (i.e. Diathim)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Angel). There are some images [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Images_of_Diathim), which show two interpretations (one more humanoid and the other more birdlike/reptilian):

[image] [image]

The humanoid images are from their first appearance in an episode of [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_of_a_Thousand_Moons).

Comment: The birdlike/reptilian is actually from the same planet but they're from underground and are known as demons, also the Angels appearance depends on the person who looks at her. So angels are literally the most beautiful aliens.

Comment: I'm guessing they exist to balance out the Devaronians.

Comment: @Andrew Sounds interesting. I wonder whether that's been inspired by *Babylon 5*, a show which actually had the same *angelic appearance changing* in there for one alien race (the *Vorlons*).

Comment: OMG. is there ANYTHING that Star Wars didn't retcon?